# Mask numpy array with a range of values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy structured array with one of the columns called 'time' I want to restrict my data where the `'time'` column is in a certain range. I tried this:

```
time_restricted_data = Data[ (Data['time'] > 0.6) & (Data['time'] < 0.7) ]
```

But that returned all the data where `Data['time'] > 0.6`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm a little confused what `Data` is...you're indexing it with a string and then later your indexing it with something which (probably) isn't a string.  Could provide a little more context code in your example?

Comment: @mgilson numpy arrays can be indexed by arrays of bools, the effect of which is to extract a subset of the array corresponding to the 'true' bool elements. I'm not familiar with structured arrays (which can be indexed by strings) but I have had problems indexing a normal array A using a bool array B, in the case where B needs one or more dimensions expanded to fit the shape of A.

Comment: @greggo -- I understand that numpy arrays can be indexed by arrays of bools.  I just think that we need to know how he has it set up so that `Data` can be indexed by a string ("time") and (presumably) an array of bools at the same time...It's possible that he just needs to do `time_restricted_data = Data["time"][...]` (e.g. if Data is really a dict holding numpy arrays and he forgot to mention that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong in your example, i.e. I can't confirm it, and I think what you wrote should work as expected:

```
In [19]: Data = np.zeros(100,dtype=[('time', np.float), ('y',np.float)])

In [20]: Data['y'] = np.random.uniform(size=100)

In [21]: Data['time'] = np.random.uniform(size=100)

In [22]: print Data[ (Data['time'] > 0.6) & (Data['time'] < 0.7) ]
[(0.6309334093696576, 0.5898588768194092)
 (0.6026040512366535, 0.4260650141076221)
 (0.6587399844526572, 0.033397798015253444)
 (0.6863639946779522, 0.67002523603246)
 (0.6522035987367735, 0.948019085443445)
 (0.6809894254849801, 0.5131390279565994)
 (0.6311277013562147, 0.5746610745753917)
 (0.6324174554481182, 0.8587836614681397)
 (0.6542221804687635, 0.9706926940115863)
 (0.671321726341415, 0.7446681474117195)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains how you can index a np array by a string and boolean values -- I'd never seen this done before, although it seems like it could be quite useful.

Comment: Well I tried again what I had tried before and it works. Your solution is correct. I must have had a typo somewhere before.